# F# Develop a function counting the number of branches containing only "leaves"

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have expression - `(cos(9**5)-cos(8*5))*(sin(3+1)**exp(6*6))`. 
I present this expression in type -

```
type common = 
         Exp of common*common 
       | Sin of common
       | Cos of common
       | Bin of common*string*common
       | Digit of float
       | Exponent of common

let expr = Bin(Bin(Cos(Exp(Digit(9.0),Digit(5.0))),"-",Cos(Bin(Digit(8.0),"*",Digit(5.0)))),"*",Exp(Sin(Bin(Digit(3.0),"+",Digit(1.0))),Exponent(Bin(Digit(6.0),"*",Digit(6.0)))));
```

I have function that calculate expression -

```
let rec evalf com = 
        match com with
        Digit(x) -> x
        |Exp(d1,d2) -> let dig1 = evalf(d1)
                       let dig2 = evalf(d2)
                       System.Math.Pow(dig1,dig2)
        |Sin(d) -> let dig = evalf(d) 
                   System.Math.Sin(dig)
        |Cos(d) -> let dig = evalf(d) 
                   System.Math.Cos(dig)
        |Exponent(d) -> let dig = evalf(d) 
                        System.Math.Exp(dig)
        |Bin(d1,op,d2) -> let dig1 = evalf(d1)
                          let dig2 = evalf(d2)
                          match op with
                          | "*" -> dig1*dig2
                          | "+" -> dig1+dig2
                          | "-" -> dig1-dig2
```

I need develop a function counting the number of branches containing only "leaves". Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defines "leaves" as digits, then to count the number of branches containing only "leaves" you would need to count the number of expressions that only reference digits.

This can be achieved with a recursive function similar to `evalf`, that returns 1 for branches with only "leaves"/digits and recurses for the non-digit cases e.g.

```
let rec count expr =
  match expr with
  | Expr(Digit(_),Digit(_) -> 1
  | Expr(d1,d2) -> count d1 + count d2
  | Sin(Digit(_)) -> 1
  | Sin(d) -> count d
  // ... for all cases
```

A similar technique can be used to simplify an expression tree, for example a binary operation (`Bin`) on 2 numbers could be matched and simplified to a single number. This might be used for example as a compiler optimization step.